# How do I check if an input is an integer or not in python?

Tags: python, input, types

So I am trying for my program to print the message "That is not an integer!" if the user inputs something that is not an integer basically, I thought this was how you would do that but apparently isn't, could anyone tell me what I am doing wrong please?

```
user_number = input()
if type(user_number) != int:
  print("That's not an integer number.")
```

Comment: Is this python 2 or 3?

Comment: Use a `try/except` block to try to convert the string to an integer using `int()`.

Comment: use `user_number.isdigit()` will return `True` or `False`

Comment: Python 2.7.10  /

Comment: @stack doesn't work if you want to accept negative

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try to convert the input to integer with `try/except`:

```
user_number = input()

try:
    int(user_number)
except:
    print("That's not an integer number.")
```